# How to hide list ribbon when opened as a modal popup

Tags: ribbon, modal-dialog

I have created list items links. When user clicks on them, the DispForm.aspx gets opened as a modal popup. I want to hide the ribbon that comes on the top. I have used javascript code to open list items as a modal popup. Please suggest how to hide the list ribbon using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

add this CSS to the page you want to open as modal

`/* hide ribbon in modal dialog window */
.ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow {
display: none;
}`

Comment: Please help me with javascript code.

Comment: @Ruchi you wont need javascript just add the above code to css in your page which you are opening as modal popup

Comment: function popup_broadcast(ID) {
                var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                options.width = 1200;
                options.height = 800;
                options.url = "/Lists/News%20%20Broadcasts/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + ID;           
                options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, success);
                         options.showClose = true;
                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);    
           }
This is my code that opens list item that are coming as hyperlink in a modal popup.Where should I put that css?

Comment: open your page in SharePoint designer, edit it with advance mode, you will find "<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server"> </SharePoint:StyleBlock>" tag just paste it inside that tag

Comment: WC.. you can just mark it as answer for future reference